# How to compare and get results in gui

Tags: c#

I want to show a messagebox to show risk when the ratio is too low. But it doesn't work. The last sentence is wrong.

```
private void resultbt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    double ratio = 0;
    double waist = 0;
    double height = 0;
    double Male_Risk = 0.536;

    waist = double.Parse(Waisttb.Text);
    height = double.Parse(Heighttb.Text);
    ratio = waist / height;
    MessageBox.Show("Your ratio is:  " + ratio);
    if (this.Male.Checked) {
        ratio < Male_Risk;
```

Comment: what's the error message?

Comment: Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In you last line you are camparing code inside a normal scope as a statement but its not allowed, comparison return a boolian type which may be inside a if statement or while statement or where boolian type is work. Correct code will be something like this

```
if (this.Male.Checked) {
     if(ratio < Male_Risk)
     {
         // do your stuff
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ratio < Male_Risk
```

Should be in condition like

```
if(ratio < Male_Risk)
{
MessageBox.Show("something");
}
```